# Not able to see entire text when embeded clear button in inputbox

Tags: html, css, angular, styles, p-table

In Angular, I have added clear button inside input box but after adding it I am not able to see entire text in input box as it is being overlapped. Please find detailed information below.

**HTML Code**

```
<ng-template pTemplate="input">
    <input pInputText type="text" class="col-input-grid-100" >
    <span class="mar-left">
        <button (click)="clearmail1(ri)" style="border:none; outline: none; position: relative; width:0;background-color: #fff;">
            <i class="pi pi-times"></i>
        </button>
    </span>                           
</ng-template>
```

**CSS content**

```
.col-input-grid-100{
      width: 135%;
      margin-left: -10px;
  }

.mar-left{
    margin-left:-29px;
  }
```

**Current Output: Text in input box is test3@test.com.**

[image]

[image]

As you can see in above image **"com"** is not visible clearly. I tried multiple ways but things didnt work. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

**Note:** 
**1. I want to show cross button inside input box only** 
**2. I am not using bootstrap library.**

Comment: inside input give right padding and then check.

Comment: beside this you cloud use: text overflow ellipsis, to cut the text at maximum space available

Comment: @Nisha, right padding will pull "cancel" button to right which will be out of input field.. I want it inside input field

Comment: @Zsolt8.. I want to see entire text values as I will be editing it.. if I use ellipsis it wont fulfil my need

Answer (score 0):

I tried with below code and it worked for me.

```
<span class="p-input-icon-right">
    <i class="pi pi-times" (click)="clearmail1(ri)" style="margin-right: -16px;"></i>
    <input id="email1" class="col-input-grid-100" type="text" pInputText >
  </span>
```

**Output**

[image]